# Python: unhashable type: 'list' for NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass in list of English words that are in plural form by using NLTK library. I am bit new to these concepts. The way I am writing I am not able to pass list of words into `Lem.lemmatize(words)`, because I can pass in single `words ='ants'`. What am I doing wrong? I saw some issues like this but unclear why it doesn't accept list format?

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
Lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
#words = [] 
words = ['ants', 'WOMEN', 'boys', 'needs', 'FINDS', 'binaries', 'HOBBIES', 'busses', 'wolves']
[w for w in words if w.lower() in Lem.lemmatize(words)] # 

output: 
['ant','woman','boy','need','find','binary','hobby','bus','wolf']
```

Comment: Because the function wasn't written to accept lists.

Comment: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html looks like a string is the only valid input

Answer (score 0):

Because the internal processing requires the input argument, as a whole entity, to be a hashable item for proper checking, and to guarantee invariance as you use the results.  Therefore, that lexicon *must* be an hashable type; "hashable" is a subset of "immutable".

Try converting it to a tuple.